# backslash gets to end of string when appending double quotes

Tags: c++, double-quotes

I'm finishing up a c++ program and have one last issue that I can't seem to find a fix for. I had the code `cpcmd += '"' + path + '"' + " " + '"' + dek + '"'`
after finding a question similar to mine I tried the following.

```
cpcmd += "\"" + path + "\"" + " " + "\"" + dek + "\""
cpcmd += \" + path + \" + " " + \" + dek + \"
```

The latter of which doesn't even compile.If I could avoid using double quotes I would but I need to pass commands to cmd. 
Why does adding double quotes the first way I tried cause an extra \ to be added to the end of the string I'm appending to? It gets added between the double quote and the end of the string it's being appended to.

In answer to the comment yes cpcmd is a string all variables here are.

I knew I'd be downvoted but I don't understand why. If I was able to find an answer to this question from googling I wouldn't have asked it.

In answer to comment asking for a full example the following will produce what I'm talking about in the debugger.

i

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string test = "this is a string";
    test += '"';
    std::cout << test;
}
```

Update: My apologies I got caught in looking at the debugger so much that I assumed that what's exactly shown in it for the values of the local variables is what gets passed. Again I'm sorry please don't downvote this anymore. I've voted myself to have it deleted.

Comment: is cpcmd a std::string?

Comment: of course the latter won't compile because `\"` is not a valid token outside of a string or character literal

Comment: Can you provide a complete, compileable example that produces the error?

Comment: On my system your code produces this: `this is a string"`

Comment: The code works fine here too: http://codepad.org/o53lXtW7 what exactly is your output?

Comment: Was just about to say it's probably just how your debugger is showing the values when I saw you'd spotted this yourself.